# Uploading a file into SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Reword the question... the below code inserts the data into an SQL Server database, and into the correct table however, the data is not inserted correctly... here is the code

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    string path = string.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + FileUpload1.FileName)));
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);

    OleDbConnection OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";");
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", OleDbcon);
    OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    OleDbcon.Open();

    DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    string con_str = @"Data Source=ENERGYSQL\ENERGY;Initial Catalog=ProjectHandler;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=aconyon;Password=birchall";

    SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(con_str);
    bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "StockTable";
    bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);

    OleDbcon.Close();

    Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles((Server.MapPath("~/temp/"))), File.Delete);
    //Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    Label1.Text = "Successfully inserted";
}
else
{
    //Label1.ForeColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Label1.Text = "please select ther File";
}
```

what this code does is select the far most right column, in my example Quantity, and insert just this into the database, ignoring all other rows (A and B) do i need to change the OleDbCommand to select certain rows. A(ItemName), B(Date), C(Quantity)

Comment: What is the inner exception, that is likely to give you more details about what is causing it.

Comment: solved it i think, just got an error with the database converting DateTime to int now... used this: OleDbConnection OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";");

Comment: install microsoft accsess in your pc.

Comment: I just would like to point out that SQL Server is not a blob storage and should not be used to store files... theres a huge amount of resources available on alternatives to storing blobs on relational databases...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code.

```
string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=YES;IMEX=1'", 
Server.MapPath(@"~\DownloadedExcelFilesOp4\myfile" + fileExt));// + "\\" +
FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
{
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(("Select [Demo1] ,[Demo2]  FROM [Sheet1$]"), 
   connection);
   connection.Open();
   using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use query like below to get the value of any particular column.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(("Select [Col1] ,[Col2]  FROM [Sheet1$]"), 
   connection);
```